# UIWebView added to a UIScrollView?

Tags: uiwebview, uiscrollview, swift

Hello there I'm working on this `UIWebView` in Swift. I added a url to the web view and so it worked properly. But when I added the web view into a scrollview I disabled the user interaction in the web view so it would not scroll from the web view. so I enabled the scrolling in the Scrollview and now I can scroll fine.. But when ever I try to click a button from my web view it does nothing.. Does anybody know how I can I enable the web view to be clickable inside the scrollview?

Comment: Why do you want to embed it inside a scroll view?

Comment: «Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.» https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/

Comment: @vikingosegundo actually its working very swell!! Hey but answer my other question that I posted earlier??

Comment: *«unexpected behavior can result»*. It doesn't say, that it will always fail. but if you work against apple's engineers advices you deserve the headache you may will experience one day.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Ill take those odds!!!

Comment: yeah, because then you will return here and yell at us in all-caps to fix your code.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I SAID ILL TAKE THOSE ODDS!!!!! DIDNT YOU HEAR ME!! YOU HAVENT EVEN HELPED ME IN ANY WAY SO FAR!! ONLY NEGATIVITY FROM YOU! SORRY IM JUST TRYING TO LEARN SOMETHING NEW!!

Comment: How about trying to learn it right, by valuing the documentation?

Comment: @vikingosegundo fine give me the link.. or where can I find it??

Comment: well, have a closer look — i posted it already. and usually you find apple's documentation on apple's site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the proper way to deal with your situation.

Do *not* disable user interaction in the web view. This prevents scrolling from occurring, but has the side effect of preventing other events, such as tapping.

This line should solve your problem:

```
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
```

If this is in the Storyboard, there is another way to do this. Go to the Identity Inspector (3rd tab on the right sidebar). Press the + sign underneath `Key Path` to look like the following:

[image]

Make sure the checkmark is disabled.

Comment: yea i just added the line under func ViewdidLoad and it worked fine!! thanks a lot!!